# How can I write an LLVM pass to detect redundant conditions in C / C + +

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to write an LLVM pass to detect redundant condition pattern like this in c++.

```cpp
int a = ... , b = ..., c = ...
//first if condition
if(a == b + 1 - c){
    ...//compoundStmt1
}
// not change the val of a, b ,c
...
//second if condition which is equivalent to first one
if(c == b - a + 1){ // redundant condition 
     ... //compoundStmt2
}
```

If I am able to find the equivalent condition, I may merge compoundStmt1 and CompoundStmt2.(That's my target!)

For this case, my idea is to find all conditional statements in C + + on CFG by checking whether the last sentence is a conditional branch jump instruction and the condition is ICMP or FCMP instruction, and add them to subsequent nodes, add the conditional constraints of the current node, and continue to spread to successors.

But I thought later that for the second if statement, it would actually be added `a == b + 1 - c` and `a != b + 1 - c`, which are actually equivalent to not adding them. How should I deal with it and judge that the second encounter of `c == b - a + 1` is repeated with the first one before to find out this redundant condition case.

====================

for complicated case(such as string's "==" operator call), how can I do something to check that.

```cpp
string s = "...."
//first if stmt
if(s == "abc"){
   ...
}
// not reassign s
...
...
//second if stmt with same condition 
if("abc" == s){ // redundant condition
   ...
}
```

Comment: You'll find this easier if you think in LLVM IR than if you focus on a language like C. IR may be a poor language in some respects, but it's excellent for thinking about and executing code transformation. Write or make a couple of cases to use as tests, be sure to run [CSE](https://llvm.org/doxygen/structllvm_1_1EarlyCSEPass.html). The rest of this comment may not make sense until you've done that. If a conditional branch dominates one of its targets, then you can reason about the value of the branch's argument at the target *and in any instructions dominated by the target.* Good luck.

Comment: Oh, in case you didn't know the term dominate: if you can prove that all ways to reach instruction B require running instruction A first, then A dominates B. LLVM contains helpers to reason about that.

Comment: How would this work if code for `std::string::operator==(const char*) const` is not defined in the header file? What if it is defined but calls another function that isn't (say, `strcmp`)? Looking at your problem in terms of LLVM IR, you would have two branches on the same register, which is already folded by SimplifyCFG. Registers that compute the same thing are folded by CSE or GVN. If something isn't being folded, you need to look at the LLVM IR until you understand why. If you aren't trying to optimize but merely to detect, check for branches on same register.

Comment: I run CSE pass through using `clang-12 -S -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone -fno-discard-value-names -emit-llvm -g -O0 mycase.cpp` && `opt --early pass mycase.ll`on my case, but it seems nothing changed on bitcode after CSE pass. I guess whether LLVM may not know `a == b  + 1 - c` is equivalent to `c == b - a + 1` while trying to fold the condition branch.

Comment: How can I judge whether the semantics of conditional expressions are exactly the same, and whether I need the help of constructing inequality system and satisfiability

Comment: Determining whether two Turing machines are equivalent is undecidable. What LLVM does is find redundancies as often as it can do efficiently, using a some of the best algorithms known to mankind, though there are always bugs or easy missed opportunities. As for your specific case, you didn't run `opt -sroa` before CSE. For engineering reasons, LLVM keeps each optimization as separate as possible from the others, but it means you do need to run other optimization passes to clean things up before the optimization you're interested in can have any effect. Check with `opt -O2`.

Answer (score 3):

### In fact the first case is much harder to do:

```
a == b + 1 - c

c == b - a + 1
```

In LLVM IR the right side would have only two operands for arithmetic operations. So for simplicity let's assume we need to establish equivalence between:

```
a == b - c

c == b - a
```

In LLVM this could look like:

```
%a1 = sub %b, %c
%cmp1 = ceq %a, a1

%c1 = sub %b, %a
%cmp2 = ceq %c, c1
```

And the goal is to establish that `%cmp1` and `%cmp2` are identical. You can think of the operations in terms of *DAG* (Directed Acyclic Graphs) or *Trees* in most cases e.g.,

```
      cmp1(ceq)
     /         \
    %a1(sub)    %a
   /  \
  %b  %c


      cmp2(ceq)
     /         \
    %c1(sub)    %c
   /  \
  %b  %a
```

To establish equivalence you need to make a set of tree transforms that makes both trees identical. There are algorithms to establish Tree equivalence and, unsurprisingly, [first proposed](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/The%20Design%20and%20Analysis%20of%20Computer%20Algorithms%20%5BAho,%20Hopcroft%20&%20Ullman%201974-01-11%5D.pdf) by the authors of the Dragon Book. For simple cases like small trees (<=5 nodes) and limited operands(arithmetic), you can just choose some heuristics to find equivalence. In case the sub-graph can't be reduced to a Tree and you are stuck with a DAG, it would be wiser to bail out in the interest of compile time as [DAG isomorphism isn't cheap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem#Complexity_class_GI) to establish

Even after equivalence is established, you need to check for certain invariants like dominance, non-intersecting side-effects etc. I have described few things below for the second case.

### For the second case

The problem is there is no built in operator to compare strings. So the equality will look like a function call and it becomes a non-trivial problem then. But assuming you only want to compare scalars like `int`. e.g.,

```
s == 10
// s is not modified
10 == s
```

In LLVM IR this may look like:

```
%t1 = 10
%c1 = ceq %s, %t1 # ceq = compare equal
// s is not modified.

%t2 = 10
%c2 = ceq %t2, %s
```

#### The first step is to make sure that `s` is not modified.

In some cases you may get this for 'free' in SSA representation. SSA is a declarative representation, so each variable is defined once.

#### The second step is to do 'constant propagation'.

So %t2 will removed after that.

```
%t1 = 10
%c1 = ceq %s, %t1
// s is not modified.
%c2 = ceq %t1, %s
```

#### Third step is to canonicalize the operands.

You may sort the operands in some order e.g., lexicographic order

```
%t1 = 10
%c1 = ceq %s, %t1
// s is not modified.
%c2 = ceq %s, %t1
```

#### Fourth step is to 'hash' the instructions.

With hash you can find the identical operations. Compilers use 'GVN' as hashing mechanism. GVN also accounts for ordering as described in step 3. So with GVN you can skip the third step.

#### Fifth step is to establish 'dominance'.

Essentially, all paths from the beginning of the function to `%c2` must pass through `%c1`. Then only one can replace `%c2` with `%c1`. There are APIs which makes this check trivial.

In case we want to handle the original problem of detecting that the string comparisons are equivalent, we need to hard-code the semantics of `strcmp`. For example, knowing that `strcmp(a, b)` and `strcmp(b, a)` will return the same value (0) when `a == b`. And then performing 'canonicalization of operations followed by remaining steps described above; it is tricky but doable.

References:
[GVN-PRE](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/Transforms/Scalar/GVN.cpp) is an optimization in LLVM that does what I described for the second case. There might be more checks needed for anticipability, and non-intersecting side effects, depending on the operand+operation types. What I described here is a very simple example.

[GVNHoist](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/Transforms/Scalar/GVNHoist.cpp) is another optimization that has similar checks you can find useful.

Comment: Thank you for your very attentive answer, A. K.!  I want to handle the second cases now. May I ask you again about the difference between llvm early CSE pass and gvn pass. Can I  use the combination of reassociate and early-cse pass to approximate  gvn pass ?

Comment: case may be using a bunch of heuristics to find redundancies. but gvn is more uses hashing followed by dominance etc. to find redundancies. they both eliminate different redundancies although there may be overlap.